# Set up an instance on AWS-Amazon but cannot connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection, cloud

I am fairly new at EC2 technology so I think I am missing some points. So I set up an instance which is running and had created two key pairs. I choose the instance, choose "Connect" and the site gives me instructions about that. I follow them and when I execute the ssh command returns that "network is unreachable". Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you ran the ec2 command line tools? It could be a good place to start analyzing your problem.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of command that will be ok for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay a few things to check:

1. Make sure you have the correct ports on your security group open to either your personal IP or to the world, depending on your security requirements. For example: Port Range 22, IP 0.0.0.0/0 (World) xx.xx.xx.xx/32 (personal IP)
2. Next I would make sure you are executing the command correctly.If 1 does not work can you post the command?
3. Another thing to check, although based off your error this probably isn't it, is that your have the proper permissions on your private key. chmod 600 mykey

Comment: 1. Checked the first one: There wasnt a rule for port 22 and I opened it. Nothing changed. 
2. the command is ssh -i mykey.pem myusername@public_dns(make the neccessary substitutions)
3. I changed the permissions and I get a message connection time out instead of network unreachable

Comment: Do I have to download a X.509 certificate? I got only a keypair

Comment: No. Just make sure you uploaded the proper public/private key pair. Then that command should work. If you have never logged into the server before your user name is probably root. Did you open the ssh port to the world?

Comment: Ok...I managed to connect. But now it asks me for a special passphrase. I dont remember entering something like that

Comment: Also, do I have to make changes to access the instance via browser? Instead of opening port 80

Comment: No you should be good as long as you open the correct ports to the world for the web. 0.0.0.0/0 on port 80 (or 8080 or whatever). If it is asking you for a passphase, you can make a new key on your local computer and put the public one in your .ssh/authorized_keys file on the server.

Comment: Hmm...I am not sure how to do this. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: http://crazytoon.com/2007/08/05/ssh-setting-up-public-key-authentication-over-ssh-centos-redhat-linux-fedora/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Amazon Linux the username is ec2-user, which you can then run sudo from.